# Segmented control width

Tags: ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I know the width of a Segmented Control in objective-C?

I need the value saved into an integer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a UIView, so it has a frame property telling you its dimensions.